# Блок-схема с веткой if, идущей на выход

Tags: алгоритм, блок-схема

Есть блок-схема, нужен совет, можно ли так делать и если нельзя, то как это исправить.

[image: Схема алгоритма]

Comment: я вижу только одну проблему - схема очень большая. Если это в коде одна функция/процедура, то по ней плачет рефакторинг.

Comment: скажем так, это схема процесса, и количество блоков это требования кафедры. Главная проблема в выходе в круге под номером 2. Обычно if закрывается, но тут не так. Противоречит ли это каким-то стандартам и нормам или нет?

Comment: думаю, это лучше у Вашей кафедры спросить. Как по мне - не противоречит.

Но средний блок можно переформатировать немного и тогда можно будет соединить вход и выход 2. Но здесь возможно будет нарушено требование, что бы ветка "да" была справа.

Comment: В каком смысле «закрывается»? Насколько я понял схему, (2) в средней колонке переходит к (2) в правой.

Comment: @VladD вот и получается, что if снизу не закрывается, а идет одной веткой на выход (может ли такое быть, в этом и вопрос). Может ли он так запросто из if переходить

Comment: @Alex Krass Спасибо

Comment: А, вы имеете в виду, что после then/else-блока flow должно снова схлопываться? Нет, это не обязательно, что вы.

Answer (score 2):

В ГОСТе 19.701.90 я не нашел, что бы накладывались какие-то условия по этому поводу, так что с точки зрения стандартов такая запись разрешена.

Comment: @Alex Krass а что насчет базовых структур (if  - один вход, один выход). А получается 2 по сути.

Answer (score 1):

**Так можно делать и ГОСТу не противоречит.**

Символ "**Соединитель**" - символ отображает вход в часть схемы и выход из другой части этой схемы. Используется для обрыва линии и продолжения её в другом месте (для избежания излишних пересечений или слишком длинных линий, а также, если схема состоит из нескольких страниц). Соответствующие соединительные символы должны иметь одинаковое (при том уникальное) обозначение.

P.S. "А что насчет базовых структур (if - один вход, один выход). А получается 2 по сути". Это укороченный вариант if (без else). Стандартный if - это 1 вход, 1 вариант ответа и 2 выхода.

Блок "Логический" - отображает решение или функцию переключательного типа с одним входом и двумя или более альтернативными выходами, из которых только один может быть выбран после вычисления условий, определенных внутри этого элемента. Вход в элемент обозначается линией, входящей обычно в верхнюю вершину элемента. Если выходов два или три, то обычно каждый выход обозначается линией, выходящей из оставшихся вершин (боковых и нижней). Если выходов больше трех, то их следует показывать одной линией, выходящей из вершины (чаще нижней) элемента, которая затем разветвляется.

Т.е. если выходов больше 2, то рисуем "ключ" (switch,case).